# Programs fail to render properly after video game crashes to desktop.

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, crash

After Sleeping Dogs crashed, chrome, firefox, internet explorer, flux, and steam don't properly render their UI or crash/or are unusable.

Utorrent renders and is totally usable, aero didn't crash when the game crashes which is usually the case when a game crashes.

I've tried logging off and logging back on, which doesn't work, restart does fix the problem. I'd like to know how I could narrow down the process or service which was affected by the game crashing to see if I can manually restart it instead of restarting my computer.

I'm running NV 9800GTX and all up to date drivers, chipset, graphics everything is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn down your graphics settings. Minimum vcard requirement for the game is a GeForce GT 620 512MB which is for all intensive purposes where your at.

It can really be one of two things.

1. The video drivers are crashing and then restarting.
2. The game is crashing and not releasing resources it allocated for itself.

Do chrome and other program that have display problems look fine after they crash or are restarted? If yes than I would say its #1.

If not then I imagine #2 is the culprit.

Turn your settings down, particularly post-processing effects and memory intensive settings (anti-aliasing, shadows) see if the game crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You could dry disabling the Graphics Card in Device Manager and then re-enabling it in an attempt to force a restart/reset of the graphics driver.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out next time it crashes, I'll also lower the settings.